# CSS locator: unable to locate element via code

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

Here is the links I am working on :

https://www.formula1.com/en/results.html/2017/drivers.html

Im trying to retrieve all the names under Driver column.

Following is the css selector Im using in code

```
dname = name.find_element_by_css_selector('span.hide-for-mobile').text
```

Testing the code in  css selector plugins.See the screenshot [image]

Below is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import csv

chromeDriver = "/home/manoj/workspace2/RedTools/test/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromeDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriver)
driver.get("https://www.formula1.com/en/results.html/2017/drivers.html")

driverNames = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//th[contains(.,'Driver')]")

for name in driverNames:
    dname = name.find_element_by_css_selector('span.hide-for-mobile').text
    print(dname)
    print('its done')
```

The Error Im getting at this moment is:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":"span.hide-for-mobile"}

What is that im doing incorrect. Help here would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to search for `span` elements that are *children* of each `th` in `driverNames` list... But `th` has no child elements

You might use

```
names = [pilot.text for pilot in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.hide-for-mobile')]
```

to get list of names

Comment: Perfect..Thanks much @Andersson

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.get("https://www.formula1.com/en/results.html/2017/drivers.html");
Thread.sleep(200);
for(int i=1;i<=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr/td[3]")).size();i++)
{     System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/main/article/div /div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[3]")).getText());
}
```

I tried this in java, you can convert it into python as your knowing